# Binding inside a XAML ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, caliburn.micro, multidatatrigger

I have a horrible feeling what I'm trying to do cannot be done, but here goes. Maybe there's a better way.

I have a ResourceDictionary in a separate file, being pulled into a UserControl (View):

```
<UserControl.Resources>        
    <ResourceDictionary Source="..\Resources.xaml"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

In the RD, I define some button styles, one of which includes a Condition, setting the Foreground to Red if the "IsCurrentFilter" converter returns True:

```
<Style x:Key="FilterButton" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonBase}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource IsCurrentFilter}}" Value="True"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The converter is defined in the same RD, further up:

```
<util:IsCurrentFilterConverter x:Key="IsCurrentFilter" ViewModel="{Binding}"/>
```

The problem is that the converter has no access to the view model (which it requires to do its comparison), and the `ViewModel` property simply refuses to bind to anything. The error is...

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'IsCurrentFilterConverter' (HashCode=50804710); target property is 'ViewModel' (type 'Object')
```

...which kinda makes sense, as I understand it's not in the visual tree.

So, how can I bind to the view model inside this ResourceDictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. A converter should not be bound to the viewmodel in this way. It should depend solely on its input value(s). Set up your button in such a way that the viewmodel is the button's data context or is available in a predictable place up the logical tree. Then your binding's converter can 'convert' the viewmodel into a boolean value. Even better, add a viewmodel property providing the desired boolean and bind to it instead.

Comment: I agree, it should solely depend on its input values. I started out by simply comparing the current filter from the view model directly, but apparently the ConverterParameter isn't a DependencyProperty. Anyway, unfortunately, I can't change/control the DataContext of the Button because I require it to be a Filter for styling.

Comment: To follow up, this suggestion actually just inverts the problem. Now I have access to the ViewModel but no idea which Filter is being referenced in the converter.

Comment: It's simple enough. You have two options: 1) provide the filter with a reference to the viewmodel — it's often useful for a lot of stuff; 2) make a multi-value converter and pass in both the filter and the viewmodel (find it using e.g. `{RelativeSource FindAncestor}`).

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer because it's better advice than the real answer is.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone stumbles upon this, I chose a different technique to solve the problem. However, binding inside a resource is something that's been fixed here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27432/Artificial-Inheritance-Contexts-in-WPF